# question on linear algebra-vector spaces-basis

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the space of $2\times2$ matrices over $F$. Find a basis $\{A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4\}$ for $V$ such that $A_j^2=A_j$ for each $j$?

Please solve this question I cannot solve it.

Answer (score 2):

$2\times 2$ is very small: you can afford to be systematic in a way that would be tedious if the matrices were larger. A typical $2\times 2$ matrix is $$A=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\;,$$ and its square is $$A^2=\pmatrix{a^2+bc&ab+bd\\ac+cd&bc+d^2}\;.$$ Thus, you need matrices $A$ such that

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
&a^2+bc=a\\
&ab+bd=b\\
&ac+cd=c\\
&bc+d^2=d\;.
\end{align*}\right.\tag{1}$$

Note also that the second and third equations will automatically be satisfied if $a+d=1$, so let’s try for a basis consisting of matrices of the form $$\pmatrix{a&b\\c&1-a}\;.\tag{2}$$

It may also be worth noticing that if either $a$ or $d$ **is** $1$, we need to have $bc=0$.

Now back away for a minute and think about the space; specifically, what’s the most obvious basis for it? By analogy with the standard basis for $\Bbb R^4$ it surely must be

$$\left\{\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0},\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0},\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0},\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}\right\}\;.$$

The first and last of these are of the form $(2)$ and satisfy $(1)$, so let’s hang onto them: we have half of our basis there. The other two, unfortunately, are not their own squares; they aren’t even of the form $(2)$. Try modifying each of them slightly to get something that **is** of that form. If you do it right, you’ll get matrices that can be combined with $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$ or $\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}$ to yield the matrices $\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$ and $\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}$, thereby ensuring that they, together with $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$ and $\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}$, really are a basis for $V$.

Answer (score 0):

Start by listing several $2\times 2$ matrices $A$ with the property that $A^2=A$ (use trial and error, and refine your search as you go). Try to get between 4 and 8 such matrices. Then check if they form a basis. (Knowing the dimension of the vector space you are looking at might help).